# pyinstaller fails on windows for simplest code

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

Using venv to try out a pyinstaller but runs into error.
python3.8

Simple code 1 liner:

```
print("Mic Testing 123")
```

Execute with:

```
 pyinstaller --onefile  --log-level=DEBUG .\testing123.py
```

Error

```
(pyi-env-minimal) PS C:\Users\preet\OneDrive\Desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool> pyinstaller --onefile --log-level=DEBUG testing123.py
79 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.6
79 INFO: Python: 3.8.3
79 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
95 INFO: wrote C:\Users\preet\OneDrive\Desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\testing123.spec
95 DEBUG: Testing for UPX ...
95 INFO: UPX is not available.
95 DEBUG: script: C:\Users\preet\OneDrive\Desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\testing123.py
95 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\Users\\preet\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\botvac_cmd_ui_tool',
 'C:\\Users\\preet\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\botvac_cmd_ui_tool']
95 INFO: checking Analysis
126 INFO: checking PYZ
164 INFO: checking PKG
164 INFO: Building because toc changed
164 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\preet\OneDrive\Desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\pyi-env-minimal\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\preet\onedrive\desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\pyi-env-minimal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\preet\onedrive\desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\pyi-env-minimal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\preet\onedrive\desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\pyi-env-minimal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\preet\onedrive\desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\pyi-env-minimal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 681, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\preet\OneDrive\Desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\testing123.spec", line 20, in <module>
    exe = EXE(pyz,
  File "c:\users\preet\onedrive\desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\pyi-env-minimal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 433, in __init__
    self.pkg = PKG(self.toc, cdict=kwargs.get('cdict', None),
  File "c:\users\preet\onedrive\desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\pyi-env-minimal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 199, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\preet\onedrive\desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\pyi-env-minimal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\preet\onedrive\desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\pyi-env-minimal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 259, in assemble
    fnm = checkCache(fnm, strip=self.strip_binaries,
  File "c:\users\preet\onedrive\desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\pyi-env-minimal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 220, in checkCache
    digest = cacheDigest(fnm, redirects)
  File "c:\users\preet\onedrive\desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\pyi-env-minimal\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 365, in cacheDigest
    with open(fnm, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
```

What is going on here?

**Update jul-9-2020:**
The issue seems to be with the --onefile option. The compilation happens when that option is removed. However the compiled binary doesnt work.

```
(pyi-env-minimal) PS C:\Users\preet\OneDrive\Desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\build> .\testing123\testing123.exe
Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users\preet\OneDrive\Desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\build\testing123\'.
LoadLibrary: The specified module could not be found.
```

With debug enabled

```
PS C:\Users\preet\OneDrive\Desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\dist\testing123> .\testing123.exe                                 [5620] PyInstaller Bootloader 3.x
[5620] LOADER: executable is C:\Users\preet\OneDrive\Desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\dist\testing123\testing123.exe
[5620] LOADER: homepath is C:\Users\preet\OneDrive\Desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\dist\testing123
[5620] LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
[5620] LOADER: archivename is C:\Users\preet\OneDrive\Desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\dist\testing123\testing123.exe
[5620] LOADER: No need to extract files to run; setting extractionpath to homepath
[5620] LOADER: SetDllDirectory(C:\Users\preet\OneDrive\Desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\dist\testing123)
[5620] LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
[5620] LOADER: Python library: C:\Users\preet\OneDrive\Desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\dist\testing123\
Error loading Python DLL 'C:\Users\preet\OneDrive\Desktop\botvac_cmd_ui_tool\dist\testing123\'.
LoadLibrary: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: what about pyinstaller --onefile  --log-level=DEBUG testing123.py ?

Comment: It looks like a bad environment issue. Are you sure that you are calling Pyinstaller from the env? Maybe try `python -m PyInstaller ...`.

Comment: It seems to be an issue with --onefile option. It seems to work when I remove that option. Although it compiles, the executable doesnt work.

Comment: python -m pyinstaller doesnt work : ' No module named pyinstaller'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue seems to come from installing python using the python installer.

Uninstall python completely from your system.
Use Microsoft app store to install python3.8

Use following to create virtual environmnet

```
python.exe -m venv --copy ----system-site-packages pyenv
```

Enable virtual environment and install pyinstaller:

```
.\pyenv\Scripts\activate.ps1
python.exe -m pip install PyInstaller
```

Use the same commands to install all required packages:

Use following to build your app:

```
python.exe -m PyInstaller --clean -F .\testing123.py
```

Execute the binary in dist folder. For windowed apps add '-w' after '-F'.